# Extract data from picture of experimental instrument

Tags: image-processing, data-acquisition

I need to transform many pictures of an analog clock with only on pointer ( the one of hours ) in the corresponding numerical data.
Is it possibile to do it with mathematica?  I would like to find some documentation about this.
Thanks in advance

Edit:
You suggest to give an sample image (is not a clock is a dynamometer but is the same problem, I talk about clock to simplify)
About the code I have no idea how to do it, this is why I am asking documentation. Sorry.
[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of the picture, and show what you have tried?

Comment: There is no clock and no code in the post, how we are going to start?

Comment: It is worth providing more details because the answer is most like, yes.

Comment: I edit the post to give you an idea of the image that I have, about the code I have the code to analyze the data but I have no idea on how to take data from picture.

Comment: Giuliano, is this picture of your experimental apparatus? If so, you might find some benefit in running `ImageLines` while focused in on the region of the meter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been discussed on the Wolfram Community forum:

- Classical computer vision approach:
  https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/852948
- Machine-learning approach:
  https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/884007

One could also use the [Python External Evaluation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/externalevaluationsystem/Python.html) functionality and use existing OpenCV implementations for this problem, e.g., https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/python-cv-samples/tree/master/examples/analog-gauge-reader